# Selecting random item from Javascript .filter() using React and Mongoose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

Using React and MongoDB/Mongoose, I'm trying to select a random item from the database, that meets the `true` parameter - basically, a user clicks a button to select a random fiction, or nonfiction writing prompt. Right now, when I `console.log(fictionPrompts)`, nothing is returned, and just the loading piece from my if function displays. Am I missing something with my `.filter()`? This was working properly when I just had the randomizer function to get any prompt from the database, without trying to filter for a specific type.

From Mongoose:

```
const promptSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  isFiction: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true
  },
...
```

Part of React Component:

```
const Prompts = props => {
  const [prompts, setPrompts] = useState([])
  const [currentPrompt, setCurrentPrompt] = useState({})

const getFictionPrompts = () => {
    axios(`${apiUrl}/prompts`)
      .then(res => setPrompts(res.data.prompts))
      .then(() => {
        props.alert({
          message: 'You\'ve received a prompt',
          variant: 'success'
        })
      })
      .catch(() => {
        props.alert({
          message: 'Something went wrong',
          variant: 'danger'
        })
      })

    const fictionPrompts = prompts.filter(prompt => (prompt.isFiction === true))
    const newPromptIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * fictionPrompts.length)
    setCurrentPrompt(fictionPrompts[newPromptIndex])
  }

  let promptsJsx = ''
  if (!currentPrompt) {
    promptsJsx = 'Loading...'
  } else {
    promptsJsx = currentPrompt.text
  }

  return (
    <Layout>
      <button className='btn btn-primary prompt-button' onClick={getFictionPrompts}>Get A Fiction Prompt!</button>
      <button className='btn btn-primary prompt-button' onClick={getNonFictionPrompts}>Get A Non-Fiction Prompt!</button>
      <p>{promptsJsx}</p>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Comment: Before you setCurrentPrompt what does a console.log(fictionPrompts[newPromptIndex], newPromptIndex) give you?

Comment: @Chad I get `undefined 0` when I run that

Comment: this will be due to the async nature of the call.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that you are having issues here is that `axios` still hasn't returned the data when you are trying to set `currentPrompt`.

If you update your code to the following it should work:

```
const getFictionPrompts = () => {
    axios(`${apiUrl}/prompts`)
      .then(res => {
        setPrompts(res.data.prompts);
        // use the data here
        const fictionPrompts = res.data.prompts.filter(
          prompt => prompt.isFiction === true
        );
        const newPromptIndex = Math.floor(
          Math.random() * fictionPrompts.length
        );
        setCurrentPrompt(fictionPrompts[newPromptIndex]);
      })
      .then(() => {
        props.alert({
          message: "You've received a prompt",
          variant: "success"
        });
      })
      .catch(() => {
        props.alert({
          message: "Something went wrong",
          variant: "danger"
        });
      });
  };
```